# Multiple same PartialsViews and Json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

This may already have an answer here but I can't seem to find the right search string so..

I have, almost the same as the comments in SO, a page that has many instances of the same PartialView.

The partial view has a button in it that when pressed adds a comment associated to the product the PartialView represents.

I can easily make this work if I do a full post back and all the comments are updated but it's an ugly solution.

What I need is on the button that was pressed I need a Json call to the server.  I then save the comment and pass back a new PartialView with a list of new comments.

I want to then only update the comments on the particular product that I added the comment to.

I use this in the javascript to assign to the button;

```
$(".clsTest").unbind("click").click(function(evt) {
```

But it only attaches this to the first instance of the button it finds not all.

I feel I'm missing some key element of knowledge here.  I'm not even sure I'm asking this question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no jQuery ninja but I think you need to look at the jQuery '.each' method.

Maybe something like this(?):

```
$(".clsTest").each(
    function() {
        $(this).unbind("click").click(function(evt) {
            //do your stuff...
        });
    }
);
```

HTHs
Charles

Comment: You don't need to do that. Unbind works on all matched elements. Check the docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [jQuery live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) for that. You won't have to add event handler whenever you add a new element matching the selector because jQuery will do it for you.

```
$('.clsTest').live('click', function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: +1 for trying but I think I described the problem incorectly.  Charlino got me a little closer but have created another question.